# Why is HBase Rest End Point not starting on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hbase, emr, amazon-emr, bigdata

I have a HBase Schema setup on an Amazon EMR Cluster running 3 m3.xlarge instances with Amazon Linux Image. When I issue the command 'hbase rest start' it's not starting and I'm getting the following output. What can I do?
Output:

```
[hadoop@ip-10-81-13-20 ~]$ hbase rest start
2016-08-01 08:29:27,863 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: HBase 1.2.1
2016-08-01 08:29:27,863 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Source code repository file:///workspace/workspace/bigtop.release-rpm-4.7.2/build/hbase/rpm/BUILD/hbase-1.2.1 revision=Unknown
2016-08-01 08:29:27,863 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Compiled by ec2-user on Fri Jul  8 02:16:27 UTC 2016
2016-08-01 08:29:27,863 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: From source with checksum b1b31eefd0314d3ed5fa7036ed0201e9
2016-08-01 08:29:28,870 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2-hbase.properties
2016-08-01 08:29:28,967 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2016-08-01 08:29:28,967 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSystemImpl: HBase metrics system started
2016-08-01 08:29:29,034 INFO  [main] mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2016-08-01 08:29:29,081 INFO  [main] http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.rest is not defined
2016-08-01 08:29:29,108 INFO  [main] http.HttpServer: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2016-08-01 08:29:29,109 INFO  [main] http.HttpServer: Added global filter 'clickjackingprevention' (class=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.ClickjackingPreventionFilter)
2016-08-01 08:29:29,114 INFO  [main] http.HttpServer: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context rest
2016-08-01 08:29:29,114 INFO  [main] http.HttpServer: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2016-08-01 08:29:29,114 INFO  [main] http.HttpServer: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2016-08-01 08:29:29,129 INFO  [main] http.HttpServer: HttpServer.start() threw a non Bind IOException
java.net.BindException: Port in use: 0.0.0.0:8085
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer.openListeners(HttpServer.java:1017)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:953)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.InfoServer.start(InfoServer.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.RESTServer.main(RESTServer.java:248)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer.openListeners(HttpServer.java:1012)
    ... 3 more
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Port in use: 0.0.0.0:8085
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer.openListeners(HttpServer.java:1017)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer.start(HttpServer.java:953)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.InfoServer.start(InfoServer.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.rest.RESTServer.main(RESTServer.java:248)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.http.HttpServer.openListeners(HttpServer.java:1012)
    ... 3 more
2016-08-01 08:29:29,133 INFO  [Shutdown] mortbay.log: Shutdown hook executing
2016-08-01 08:29:29,133 INFO  [Shutdown] mortbay.log: Shutdown hook complete
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question)
The defaults in AWS EMR for HBase ports are different from the regular HBase. From [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hbase-configure.html) we can say that the rest port for HBase is 8070 and the port for the UI is 8085. One could use them.
That said, there's always the -p option. Use `hbase rest start -p portnumber` to start the HBase rest server on a port number of your choice.

There's probably another process using the 8080 port that's why you can't start the HBase server using only `hbase rest start`.